# Storing a console application in Azure blob storage

Tags: dll, console-application, exe, azure-blob-storage

I have a windows console application in C# that I want to store in Azure blob storage (not file storage) and then upload it to a remote VM to run it from command-line. How can I go about doing that? I am not sure how I can package all the executables and dlls that the application needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to publish your console application into one folder, then you could use azure storage library or azure storage explorer tool to update that folder to the blob storage.

More details, you could refer to this steps:

1.Publish the console application to one folder.

[image]

2.Install the [Data movement library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) from Nuget package manager and copy the folder to the azure blob storage.

Codes as below:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("brando");


        CloudBlobDirectory blockBlob = container.GetDirectoryReference("test");

        string path = @"youconsoleapplicationpath\consoletest";

        UploadDirectoryOptions u1 = new UploadDirectoryOptions();
        u1.Recursive = true;

        TransferManager.UploadDirectoryAsync(path, blockBlob, u1, null).Wait();
```

Result:

[image]

Or you could download the [azure storage explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/), then you could directly copy the folder to the azure blob storage.

At last, you could install the [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) by cmd to download the whole folder to your VM's path and run the application.